# Hospedagem de um pequeno software javaweb na jelastic localweb

Tags: java

Fiz um curso na de java web montando um financeiro com contas a pagar e algumas coisas básicas. Algumas pessoas se interessaram . No caso para cada cliente tenho que criar um ambiente.  Sabem se eu adaptar o software para diferentes usuários, usando o banco de dados MySQL, poderá gerar algum problema?
só uma orientação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua aplicação estiver bem estruturada não vai ter problema algum.

Para ver se entendi, vc quer vender o software para diferentes clientes utilizando uma mesma base MySQL correto?

Se for isso, é questão de vc programar o software para atender este requisito.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno spy